# Rearranging a dataframe such that cells with similar values are in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I've encountered a puzzle I don't know how to solve. I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Sample     RT1       Area1     RT2      Area2     RT3      Area3
1          1.880     50        NA       NA        NA       NA
2          1.743     25        NA       NA        NA       NA
3          1.690     15        NA       NA        NA       NA
4          1.694     13        1.757    26        1.877    51
```

What I would like to do, is group cells of similar values (within 1% of each other) into the same column, using row 4 as an index. The result should look like this:

```
Sample     RT1      Area1     RT2       Area2     RT3      Area3
1          NA       NA        NA        NA        1.880    50
2          NA       NA        1.743     25        NA       NA
3          1.690    15        NA        NA        NA       NA
4          1.694    13        1.757     26        1.877    51
```

Row 4, in this case, stays put, while the rest of the dataframe rearranges around it. The trouble is, the number of columns and rows are not necessarily going to be the same between dataframes, so I need a generalized solution that will work for n columns. I frankly have no idea where to start, so I apologize for a lack of MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Cool puzzle! This might get you started, though it does **not** group values within 1%, simply by the *closest* value in the 'index' row. So, if you had two values from your input table that should go in column 3, for example, one would be omitted.

```
test_data <- structure(list(Sample = 1:4, RT1 = c(1.88, 1.743, 1.69, 1.694
), Area1 = c(50L, 25L, 15L, 13L), RT2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.757), 
Area2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 26L), RT3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.877), Area3 = c(NA, 
                                                                  NA, NA, 51L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
                                                                  ))


library(plyr)

ParseTable <- function(tbl) {
  # Pull the index row (bottom row)
  ind_row <- tbl[nrow(tbl), ]
  
  # Pull the remaining table to parse
  to_parse <- tbl[-nrow(tbl), ]
  
  # Iterate over the rows
  parsed_table <- adply(to_parse, .margins = 1, function(rw) {
    # Pull out the rows into named vectors to get their column names
    named_vec <- (unlist(rw[ , -1]))
    
    # Make an output row that is just NA values
    out_rw <- rw
    out_rw[, 2:ncol(out_rw)] <- NA
    
    # Iterate over the named vector to filter against the names of the base table
    for (col_name in names(named_vec)) {
      # Pull the value proper for processing
      cur_val <- named_vec[col_name]
      if (!is.na(cur_val)) {
      
        # Strip numerical values from the base column name
        col_name_bare <- gsub("[0-9]", "", col_name)
        
        # Filter the matching columns in the index row
        cur_row <- ind_row[, grepl(col_name_bare, names(ind_row))]
        
        # Determine which value in the index row is closest
        which_closest <- which.min(abs(cur_val - cur_row))
        
        # Pull the column index from the base table 
        col_ind_out <- which(names(to_parse) == names(cur_row)[which_closest])
        
        # Fill the out row with the current value
        out_rw[, col_ind_out] <- cur_val
      }
    }
    
    return(out_rw)
  })
  
  # Bind the parsed table back to the index row
  rbind(parsed_table, ind_row)
}
```

Output:

```
> ParseTable(test_data)
  Sample   RT1 Area1   RT2 Area2   RT3 Area3
1      1    NA    NA    NA    NA 1.880    50
2      2    NA    NA 1.743    25    NA    NA
3      3 1.690    15    NA    NA    NA    NA
4      4 1.694    13 1.757    26 1.877    51
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great jumping off point. So in that edge case, in which there are two values in, say, RT1 and RT2 that are close together and one gets omitted, I notice the corresponding Area column remains intact. Any way to have it omit both RT and Area? Also, let's say the index row is not the last row. I can find the index row separately but your code moves the index to the bottom. Any way to keep it in place?

Comment: @AlexanderKim - 1) Yes, you could do that (for example by keeping track of the column name for each RT that is processed, and then checking against any time you assign a value to `out_rw`). 2) Yes, add an argument to the function such as `index_row` so that the `ind_row` and `parsed_row` subsetting refers to that value instead of just `nrow()`, then after you `rbind()` at the end, use indexing (eg `data.frame[new_order, ]` to rearrange as desired. Unfortunately I won't have time to make these changes for a few days so I'd encourage you to play around and fiddle!